# Good Azlanti Dungeon Adventure?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, published-adventures

In my [Pathfinder pirate campaign](http://geek-related.com/session-summaries/reavers-on-the-seas-of-fate/), the PCs have reached the cultist-infested Sun Temple Colony in Azlant from [Lost Cities of Golarion](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8i8t?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Lost-Cities-of-Golarion); I'm also using Open Design's [Sunken Empires](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8ezw?Sunken-Empires) to give it that Atlantis/Mu feel. They just ran through From [Shore to Sea](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8evj?Pathfinder-Module-From-Shore-to-Sea) lately and so are somewhat used to the weird Azlanti architecture and will-o-wisp streetlights and everything. What's a good level 6-8 dungeon type adventure that fits well with the Azlanti look/feel/themes I could use on the island (they have a treasure map to the island I'd like to pay off)?

I saw that the last part of Revenge of the Kobold King is of appropriate level and Azlanti themed, but is pretty short. I don't know what is in all the Pathfinder Society modules. Any good small to medium dungeon adventures that have that trippy Azlanti feel to them?

(I have pretty much every Dungeon mag and most of Paizo's stuff except the Society adventures, plus loads of 2e and 1e gear, so if you can name it it might help me.)

[Edit: I ended up using Rana Mor from Dungeon #86 and reskinning it as a hidden temple to Zura - the moat was blood, everyone was undead, etc.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [*Savage Tide Adventure Path*](http://paizo.com/dungeon/products/issues/savageTide) in *Dungeon Magazine* #139-150, specifically #144 has the *Lightless Depths* chapter which contains the ruins of Golismorga, with architecture that might fit the Azlanti theme.

You might also check out [*The Night Below*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Below%3a_An_Underdark_Campaign) (2nd Edition) boxed set had an Aboleth city, *Great Shaboath* which might tie in nicely with material from *Sunken Empires*.

Comment: Ah, I ran Night Below back in 2e days, really enjoyed it, looking for something more tightly scoped (tomb or small dungeon, not whole city/megadungeon).  I'll check Savage Tide in #144 tonight, thanks.

Comment: Hmm; Lightless Depths is a little more aboleth city than I'd like too (plus one of my players is GMing it for another group) - was hoping for more the Azlanti and less the Aboleth side of things.